# Is a business associates contract required to use hosted R&D services?

Tags: cloud-computing, hipaa

I'm on the "configuration management" team which, among other things, means I'm responsible for R&D systems, like: source control, issue tracking, team collaboration (wiki), etc.

These are not production, customer systems with any patient or transactional data.

Every time I talk about migrating these R&D systems to hosted services (we're running a small data center on-premises) I get a lot of heat about HIPAA and business associates agreements.

I read a little on [business associates](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/understanding/coveredentities/contractprov.html) and it doesn't seem to me to apply to these R&D systems.

Any advice?

Comment: I'd categorize this question under risk managment and/or policies, per the help center. Can I make that more obvious with a different wording? Many similar questions exist: http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhipaa%5D+baa